# When making a remote COM call, where does the proxy stub DLL need to be registered?

Tags: com, registry, dcom

I have a client-server setup, a module `SomethingApp.exe` implementing IDL defined interface `ISomething` lives on the server; in addition `SomethingPS.dll` is created by the IDL compiler as a stub for `ISomething`

I access `ISomething` from a remote client PC, which runs up `SomethingApp.exe` on the server. My understanding is that all the COM registry stuff in this scenario belongs on the server, is that right? i.e. the proxy stub does not need to be distributed/registered on the client PC, because the implementation is not on that PC?

Answer (score 1):

The proxy stub **does** need to be installed on the client PC - it's this proxy that exposes the ISomething interface to be called by the code on the client. If it's not registered on the client PC the client code won't know what to call and you'll get an exception.

We have a similar set up here - server side COM+ applications that we export to proxies and install on client machines. Without the proxy being installed on the client it doesn't work.

Edit: I see now you've edited that `SomethingPS.dll` is the proxy stub you've created using the IDL compiler. I believe that this should be installed on the client machine.

Comment: I've edited a bit. `ISomething` is implemented on the server (SomethingApp.exe) but obtained and called into from the client through DCOM. It sounds like the ProxyStub needs to be on every PC that calls `CoCreate[Ex](..., ISomething)`, basically?

Comment: @Mr.Boy yes - I don't create proxies using IDL compiler but by exporting COM+ apps but this also uses DCOM and the call to `CoCreate` requires the interface to be installed on the client machine.